# Set timeout on AJAX without $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, ajax, load, modal-dialog

I want to set timeout after 2 seconds loading data. I am new in ajax so please clarify through my code...because i have already see many (set time out on ajax) answer but every one do through $.ajax().

how I can do through .load() ? It is possible or not ?

My AJAX code 1:

```
// Start of our new ajax code
        if (!url) {
            url = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').attr('action');
        }
        url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index"); // New Code
        var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
        data += '&isAjax=1';
        jQuery('#ajax_loader').show();
        try {
            jQuery.ajax( {
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data : data,
                success : function(data) {
                    jQuery('#ajax_loader').hide();
                    parent.setAjaxData(data,true);
                }
            });
            jQuery("#productOptions").modal('hide');
        } catch (e) {
            //alert(e);
        }
        // End of our new ajax code
```

2:

```
// AJAX product options modal
$('.optionsTrigger').on('click', function() {
    var target, url;
    target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).load(url, function(){
        $(target).modal({
            show: true
        });
    });
});
$('#productOptions').on('hidden', function() {
    $('#productOptions').html('<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("img/loading.gif"); ?>" id="optionsLoading" />');

    window.setTimeout("Tick()", 2000);

    function Tick()
     {

     }  
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, wrap your head around the fact that Ajax is *asynchronous* (like `setTimeout`) - the callbacks are called somewhen in the future.

How to timeout? You could use

```
var request = jQuery.ajax(…);
setTimeout(function() {
    request.abort();
}, 2000);
request.done(function callback(){ … });
```

But it's much simpler than that, jQuery already has a `timeout` parameter for it's [`ajax()` option object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

However, this is not possible using [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - here not the jqXHR object is returned, but the current jQuery DOM-selection. Either, you have to [globally configure ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/), or you don't use `load` and build the method yourself - it's not that hard, see [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L164)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has the [`ajaxSetup()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup) available. You can set all options to the normal `ajax()` method there, including the `timeout` option. The settings set there should also be available when you call your AJAX request via `load()`.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. One caveat: if affects all future AJAX calls that don't specify a timeout.